# A result on prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hi everyone

This is my first post...
I do mathematics from home... ie., not attached with any institution...
I have deduced some results...

$\lim \inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{d_n}{\log p_n} = 0$

and, for constants $A,B$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log p_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{d_i}{p_{i+1}} = A$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log p_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{d_i}{p_{i}} = B$

Where, $p_n$ is the nth prime... $d_n = p_{n+1} - p_n$

My question is:
Do you think these results are good ?

Comment: Your result is due to Goldston and Yildirim, and was only established in the last 10 years, using sophisticated sieve theory techniques. It would be very impressive if you had found an easy/elementary proof of this. 

Comment: First result, that is.

Comment: The other two claims can easily be derived from known power bounds on prime gaps, but still, it would be interesting to see how you do them. So, yes, this is high quality work (provided it is correct, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the good news!!! But that actually made me more skeptical... because in maths mostly, "easy implies wrong"... and if there are any errors... I'd love to debug them, now that I know the problem is so important :D

I have posted my paper here:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.4646

Would love to get comments...

Comment: I am no specialist in analytic number theory, but from what I know from analysis the limit computation (10) is clearly wrong.  You have the product of two factors, the first (p_n/log p_n) of which goes to infinity and the second goes to zero, and so it does not follow that the product goes to zero.

Comment: @Leonid, I think you're right and you should post your observation as an answer -- it could be accepted then.

Comment: Well, i didnt want to actually apply the PNT... but just to give an idea, then it would have looked like

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim \inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{d_n}{\log p_n} 
 & = \lim \inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n}{\log p_n} \log \left( \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \right)\\
 & = \lim \inf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{\log n + \log \log n} \log \left( 1 + 1/n \right)^n\\
 & = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}



Comment: The limit you write now is equal to 1 and not to 0.  (Neither does the second equation sign in your formula seem to be justified from PNT.)

Comment: @leonid: yea... sorry for that... but anyways, i am not using PNT for that equation, just tried to give an idea, but damn!!! 

Comment: but leonid, you struck a great point there...
here are my thoughts on it...

lim inf p(n+1)/p(n) = 1 implies lim inf (p(n+1)/p(n))^p(n) = 1
implies lim inf log((p(n+1)/p(n))^p(n)) = 0
implies lim inf p(n)log(p(n+1)/p(n)) = 0

Does this resolve it?

Comment: @Ilya: I did as you requested.

Comment: @rpg: your first implication is not justified.  This is called "1 to the power \infty", a kind of expression whose limit you cannot know just from knowing the limits of the constitutient subexpressions.  You are repeating your original mistake here, in a slightly disguised form.

Comment: It's fine to ask, "are these results known and does somebody have a reference?" But this has turned into a game of "debug my proof for me," which (in this form at least) is not appropriate for Math Overflow. I'm closing the question (direct discussion about it to http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/124). If the question is edited to sharpen it (i.e. make it a question that has an answer), or if somebody otherwise convinces me (or another moderator, or five 3k+ rep users), the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am no specialist in Analytic Number Theory, nor did I read the whole paper under the link.  I just looked into the end of the argument, and there is a limit computation (10) there.

From what I know from Analysis, this computation is clearly wrong, not in the sense that the answer is necessarily wrong, but in the sense that the premises do not justify the conclusion.  The author attempts to compute the lower limit of the product $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{p_n}{\log p_n}\log\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}\right)$$
as the product of the limits.  He replaces the second factor with $log(1)=0$ and proceeds to claim that the lower limit of the product is $0$.  However, even though the (lower) limit of the second factor may well be $0$, the limit of the first factor is clearly $\infty$, so one cannot compute the lower limit of the product in this way.

Comment: check the updated paper :)
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.4646

Cheers!!!

Comment: Leonid above correctly says that you are now computing $1^\infty$: you can't just claim it's equal to 1. @Leonid, I think it's more reasonable to move discussion here. @rpg16, once you arrive to understanding with Leonid, please accept his answer!

Comment: @Ilya: unfortunately I perceive very little point in continuing the discussion.  Let me simply state that my answer applies to the prepint arxiv:0912.4646 version 4 and not to any later or other version.

Comment: @rpg16: Looking at the new answer, I don't think it is correct. You do correctly move the $p_n$ term inside the log, but now this ratio to the $p_n$ can end up being quite large (I don't think the limit is 1, in fact I think--but am no expert on this subject--that there are results on what this limit is). So your next step replacing it all by a 1 is probably incorrect.

Comment: OMG, I did not realize that I was commenting on a version of a paper that was not yet permanently saved.  The author replaced it, and now there are no traces left of what I have commented on in my answer.  I should have known better than falling prey to that.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the first limit to diverge like $\log\log n$ ... Here is why: we know that $p_n \sim n \log n$ while on average $d_i \sim \log i$ so i would expect your second limit to be about $\log n + \log\log n - \sum_{i=1}^n{(\log i)/(i \log i)} \sim \log\log n$ ... On the other hand if you can prove that this limit is bounded I think that would be a surprising result by itself! I'd be happy to hear what others have to say about it...